# Pythonnet using on .Net core dlls

Tags: python, python.net

I have a library built using .NET CORE 3.1. I imported the C# library and followed the steps i.e. `load(''coreclr")`. Importing the DLL works, but when I call a method that is connecting to SQL Server and fetches the data. I am getting the following error i.e. `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform`. The C# Library works fine when I tested with a Console Application. Any help is appreciated.

```
from pythonnet import load
load("coreclr")
import clr
assemblykdir = r"Path to Dll's"
sys.path.append(assemblykdir)
```